# unable to input string into a struct

Tags: c, string, struct, scanf

I have a header file structs.h as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *name;
}
student;
```

In the file structs.c,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "structs.h"

int main()
{
    student students[3];

    scanf("%s", &students[0].name);

    return 0;

}
```

The scanf statement gives an error since it says %s is of type char* but argument is of type char**. Removing the & gives a segmentation fault.

How else would I write this? It is a array within an array of struct variables but it should be able to take input...

Comment: Where's the space allocated for the `name` to point at?  Hint: … it isn't!  You need to fix that.  If you have a POSIX system that supports it, the `%ms` conversion specification to [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) will do the memory allocation for you.  This works on Linux; it does not work on macOS (or Mac OS X, and presumably not on *BSD either).  Otherwise, you have to allocate the memory yourself.

Comment: You don't need to pass a pointer to pointer, just `students[0].name` will do as it's alreay a pointer to an array. Also, this will be undefined behaviour as `name` is not initialized.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help...I got it